# Laravel Multiple Upload File

Tags: laravel, multiple-file-upload

How to show uploaded files using multiple upload files?

With data like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets consider you name is in this variable = $uploadedFiles;

```
$uploadedFiles = ["file1","file2","file3"];
$temp = json_decode($uploadedFiles);
foreach($temp as $name) {
  echo $name;
}
```

It will print your file name 1 by 1

Comment: Thank you for your solutions, I tried it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It just names you need the files also

but if you want to store only that names then you can do it by taking a loop for that variable array

if it is not an array then convert to array using `json_decode(array)`

Comment: I want to store in the table and also store files in the folders. By the way, thanks for your suggestion, I will try it.